# Responsive Design - Amend JQuery to change action for mobiles and tablets

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have the following code which on mouse over hides the image and displays the content of the div underneath and once the div is clicked it takes you to another page.  Mouse Overs dont work on tablets etc and so that instead of hover  I changed the hover to a click to  display the div contents.  However when I change the hover to click, the div displays and then goes through to next page in one action.  I need this to be two clicks.  Can anyone advise on how I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Custom settings
    var style_in = 'easeOutBounce';
    var style_out = 'jswing';
    var speed_in = 1000;
    var speed_out = 250;

    //Calculation for corners
    var neg = Math.round($('.qitem').width() / 2) * (-1);  
    var pos = neg * (-1);  
    var out = pos * 2;
    var pos_h = Math.round($('.qitem').height() / 2);   

    $('.qitem').each(function () {

        //grab the anchor and image path
        url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

        //remove the image
        $('img', this).remove();

        //append four corners/divs into it
        $(this).append('<div class="topLeft"></div><div class="topRight"></div><div class="bottomLeft"></div><div class="bottomRight"></div>');

        //set the background image to all the corners
        $(this).children('div').css('background-image','url('+ img + ')');

        //set the position of corners
        $(this).find('div.topLeft').css({top:0, left:0, width:pos, height:pos_h});  
        $(this).find('div.topRight').css({top:0, left:pos, width:pos, height:pos_h});   
        $(this).find('div.bottomLeft').css({bottom:0, left:0, width:pos, height:pos_h});
        $(this).find('div.bottomRight').css({bottom:0, left:pos, width:pos, height:pos_h}); 

    }).hover(function () {  //change to click

        //animate the position
        $(this).find('div.topLeft').stop(false, true).animate({top:neg, left:neg}, {duration:speed_out, easing:style_out});
        $(this).find('div.topRight').stop(false, true).animate({top:neg, left:out}, {duration:speed_out, easing:style_out});   
        $(this).find('div.bottomLeft').stop(false, true).animate({bottom:neg, left:neg}, {duration:speed_out, easing:style_out});  
        $(this).find('div.bottomRight').stop(false, true).animate({bottom:neg, left:out}, {duration:speed_out, easing:style_out}); 

    },

    function () {

        //put corners back to the original position
        $(this).find('div.topLeft').stop(false, true).animate({top:0, left:0}, {duration:speed_in, easing:style_in});  
        $(this).find('div.topRight').stop(false, true).animate({top:0, left:pos}, {duration:speed_in, easing:style_in});   
        $(this).find('div.bottomLeft').stop(false, true).animate({bottom:0, left:0}, {duration:speed_in, easing:style_in});
        $(this).find('div.bottomRight').stop(false, true).animate({bottom:0, left:pos}, {duration:speed_in, easing:style_in}); 

    }).click (function () {

        //go to the url
        window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');  
    });

});
```

Comment: Seing the html would help a bit, maybe an example on [jsffidle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace `$.hover()` with click, you must replace the last `$.click` with [`$.dblclick`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/), otherwise the two click handlers will be triggered at the same time.

Comment: yes thats works, thanks.  Don't suppose you know how I would go about adding code to detect browser size wihtout having two lots of code almost identical.   ie.  var width = $(window).width();  
   if (width < 480) {

Comment: @LeeTee To minimize code duplication, you could extract hover and click functions, and depending on the window width, bind them to hover/click or click/dblClick.